# How to find element by attribute and text in a singe locator?

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

How can I find an element using Playwright using a single locator phrase?

My element is:

```html
<div class="DClass">Hello</div>
```

I wish to find the element by its class and text:

```
myElement = self.page.locator('text="Hello",[class="DClass"]')
```

Why it does not work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you separate the selectors with a `,` that's an `or`. You can chain selectors using `>>`.

```
myElement = self.page.locator('text="Hello" >> [class="DClass"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following locator:

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright  # 1.40.0


with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.set_content('<div class="DClass">Hello</div>')
    loc = page.locator('.DClass:text-is("Hello")')
    print(loc.text_content()) # => Hello
    browser.close()
```

`.DClass` is generally preferred to `[class=""]` attribute syntax because it doesn't fail if other classes are present on the element. `[class=""]` is an exact match.

On the other hand, the `:text-is("")` pseudoselector is an exact match. Text is more often the sort of thing where you want exact precision, unlike CSS classes. But if you do want to use a substring on the text, `:text("")` is available.

If you're writing an assertion, you can use

```py
expect(page.locator(".DClass")).to_have_text("Hello")
```

although keep in mind that CSS classes aren't [user-visible](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/locators#quick-guide) and are discouraged for locators.

Comment: Why did you import `expect` from `playwright.sync_api`?

Comment: @5rod because I use the same import for starting all my answers and forgot to remove it. Most of the time, I use it. Good catch.